# Parquet-backed pyspark doesn't appear to be using partitions to cull when querying - why not?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a project which is currently quite small/simple in terms of data volume.  Time-series data with a half-dozen fields, ~1M rows and 22MB per day of data.

I'm still learning the ins and outs of PySpark's use of parquet, but the one thing I feel clear on is that the partition keys are used as a first-pass index-like filter to cull irrelevant data when querying.  If you partition on `K` and have partition dirs `K=A`, `K=B`, `K=C`, then if `K=A` appears in the PySpark-SQL query, the subtrees under `K=B` and `K=C` should never even be inspected.

My data is partitioned by date, in format YYYY-MM-DD, and sorted by (integer epoch) timestamp before the file was written out. Data is stored on local disk, and the "cluster" is a master and single worker on a development machine.  There is a secondary partition `satellite_id` having either integer value 1 or two, so every day has two local files.

Querying a small temporal slice of data takes ~300ms on my local deployment with one week of data present in the parquet path.  When a parquet path containing a *year* of data is used (so ~700 files, total), the query time jumps to 5000ms.  I noticed I'd neglected to include the partition column in my query - whoops!
So I fixed it... and nothing changed.

```py
    @classmethod
    def select(cls, fields: Iterable[str], from_dt: datetime, to_dt: datetime) -> List[pyspark.Row]:
        table_name = 'someTableName'

        spark = get_spark_session()
        table_df = spark.read.parquet(cls.parquet_path)
        table_df.createOrReplaceTempView(table_name)

        fields_str = ', '.join(fields)
        from_rcvtime_intg = cls.dt_to_rcvtime_intg(max(from_dt, timestamp_epoch))
        to_rcvtime_intg = cls.dt_to_rcvtime_intg(to_dt)

        query = f"""
            select {fields_str}, rcv_timestamp
            from {table_name}
            where
                {PARQUET_TEMPORAL_PARTITION_KEY} >= '{from_dt.date().isoformat()}'
                and {PARQUET_TEMPORAL_PARTITION_KEY} <= '{to_dt.date().isoformat()}'
                and rcvtime_intg >= {from_rcvtime_intg}
                and rcvtime_intg <= {to_rcvtime_intg}
        """

        records_df = spark.sql(query)
        return records_df.collect()
```

Given my understanding of PySpark parquet, with the YYYY-MM-DD partition key present in the query, spark should immediately cull 364 of the available 365 directories (728 of 730 files) before descending into the data files themselves, and the query execution time should therefore be roughly constant despite the ~50x data volume.  So it looks like I'm missing something, and spark's not making use of that "index".

Dumping the query plan yields the following, from which nothing jumps out at me

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project ['ang_accl_z, 'lin_accl_x, 'ang_accl_y, 'rcv_timestamp, 'lin_accl_z, 'satellite_id, 'lin_accl_y, 'ang_accl_x, 'rcv_timestamp]
+- 'Filter ((('temporal_partition_key >= 2023-06-06) AND ('temporal_partition_key <= 2023-06-06)) AND (('rcvtime_intg >= 739324800) AND ('rcvtime_intg <= 739324860)))
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation [GRACEFO_1A_full_resolution], [], false
== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
ang_accl_z: double, lin_accl_x: double, ang_accl_y: double, rcv_timestamp: timestamp, lin_accl_z: double, satellite_id: int, lin_accl_y: double, ang_accl_x: double, rcv_timestamp: timestamp
Project [ang_accl_z#7, lin_accl_x#2, ang_accl_y#6, rcv_timestamp#8, lin_accl_z#4, satellite_id#9, lin_accl_y#3, ang_accl_x#5, rcv_timestamp#8]
+- Filter (((temporal_partition_key#10 >= cast(2023-06-06 as date)) AND (temporal_partition_key#10 <= cast(2023-06-06 as date))) AND ((rcvtime_intg#0L >= cast(739324800 as bigint)) AND (rcvtime_intg#0L <= cast(739324860 as bigint))))
   +- SubqueryAlias gracefo_1a_full_resolution
      +- View (`GRACEFO_1A_full_resolution`, [rcvtime_intg#0L,rcvtime_frac#1L,lin_accl_x#2,lin_accl_y#3,lin_accl_z#4,ang_accl_x#5,ang_accl_y#6,ang_accl_z#7,rcv_timestamp#8,satellite_id#9,temporal_partition_key#10])
         +- Relation [rcvtime_intg#0L,rcvtime_frac#1L,lin_accl_x#2,lin_accl_y#3,lin_accl_z#4,ang_accl_x#5,ang_accl_y#6,ang_accl_z#7,rcv_timestamp#8,satellite_id#9,temporal_partition_key#10] parquet
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [ang_accl_z#7, lin_accl_x#2, ang_accl_y#6, rcv_timestamp#8, lin_accl_z#4, satellite_id#9, lin_accl_y#3, ang_accl_x#5, rcv_timestamp#8]
+- Filter ((isnotnull(temporal_partition_key#10) AND isnotnull(rcvtime_intg#0L)) AND (((temporal_partition_key#10 >= 2023-06-06) AND (temporal_partition_key#10 <= 2023-06-06)) AND ((rcvtime_intg#0L >= 739324800) AND (rcvtime_intg#0L <= 739324860))))
   +- Relation [rcvtime_intg#0L,rcvtime_frac#1L,lin_accl_x#2,lin_accl_y#3,lin_accl_z#4,ang_accl_x#5,ang_accl_y#6,ang_accl_z#7,rcv_timestamp#8,satellite_id#9,temporal_partition_key#10] parquet
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [ang_accl_z#7, lin_accl_x#2, ang_accl_y#6, rcv_timestamp#8, lin_accl_z#4, satellite_id#9, lin_accl_y#3, ang_accl_x#5, rcv_timestamp#8]
+- *(1) Filter ((isnotnull(rcvtime_intg#0L) AND (rcvtime_intg#0L >= 739324800)) AND (rcvtime_intg#0L <= 739324860))
   +- *(1) ColumnarToRow
      +- FileScan parquet [rcvtime_intg#0L,lin_accl_x#2,lin_accl_y#3,lin_accl_z#4,ang_accl_x#5,ang_accl_y#6,ang_accl_z#7,rcv_timestamp#8,satellite_id#9,temporal_partition_key#10] Batched: true, DataFilters: [isnotnull(rcvtime_intg#0L), (rcvtime_intg#0L >= 739324800), (rcvtime_intg#0L <= 739324860)], Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[file:/nomount/masschange/data_volume_mount/full-resolution], PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(temporal_partition_key#10), (temporal_partition_key#10 >= 2023-06-06), (temporal_parti..., PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(rcvtime_intg), GreaterThanOrEqual(rcvtime_intg,739324800), LessThanOrEqual(rcvtime_int..., ReadSchema: struct<rcvtime_intg:bigint,lin_accl_x:double,lin_accl_y:double,lin_accl_z:double,ang_accl_x:doubl...
```

Am I misunderstanding how PySpark uses parquet, fundamentally?  Or is there something I need to *do* to actually leverage partitions during queries, beyond including the relevant field in my Spark-SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses Hadoop's file system code to get the list of which files and paths are relevant.  It does this *before* any partition pruning is performed.  The more partitions, and files in them, you have the slower the file search.  In order to mitigate this it's done in a number of threads after the top level partition scan.  Each file in the system is read for stats at least.

On Azure ADLS2 this searching is incredibly slow (performance improvements have been made in the last years though) and made worse by multi-threading as it eats into the maximum concurrent usage of 50k per storage account, so if you have multiple operations even on different files you'll risk throttling and backout by ADSL.

If you are able to use Delta this removes the file search by storing the files (blocks) used in the ledger, so the number of file reads is significantly minimised.

Comment: As OP stated, his data resides locally. Phys plan also confirms this: `...InMemoryFileIndex(1 paths)[**file:**/nomount/masschange/data_volume_mount/full-resolution]...`

Comment: I can confirm, at least, that the scanning doesn't appear to be the issue.  I tested a raw pyarrow implementation of the same filtering logic (though with the satellite partition removed, so half the file count) - 100ms for the week of data, 150ms for the full year.

Comment: Test the actual spark implementation by using [mergeSchema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging) , without specifying a schema, "load" the parquet and then call and time df.schema() to rule that out on the actual code used.